# Custom Tax Calculation in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, tax-calculation

I am new to magento 2, i want to calculate the tax based on the custom field value which will present in customer billing address form. if user enters a value in the field the custom calculation should happen else default tax calculation should happen.
Any help please.
Thanks in advance.